# Обработка строки с помощью LINQ в C#

Tags: linq, c#

Исходная строка:

```
string before = "Sdg35%6J;><eg3Fh";
```

Итоговая строка:

```
string after = "SdgJegFh";
```

Как получить из первой строки вторую, оставив только буквы, используя LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string after = new string(before.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

или

```
string after = new string(before.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```